# Ignore .spring-boot-devtools.properties in tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

Spring Boot devtools allow you to define global configuration outside of your application sources by placing a file `.spring-boot-devtools.properties` into your home directory, which takes precedence over the bundled configuration, according to:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

However, this file also applies when running unit tests, so if you have tests that depend on some configuration, either the defaults defined in bundled `application.properties` or in test-specific properties defined by `@TestPropertySource`, they are still overridden by the global values and your build breaks.

Is there some reasonable way how to either ignore the `.spring-boot-devtools.properties` or to exclude the devtools from the test classpath altogether (we're using Gradle)?

Comment: There is a related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5307